# Как создать подобный фильтр товаров в WooCommerce?

Tags: woocommerce

Здравствуйте.

Может, подскажете, как сделать подобные фильтры, или направите на темы, где можно почитать об этом.

То есть нужно, чтобы можно было выбрать два пункта из одного раздела и чтобы выбранные отображались внизу.
Читал про атрибуты, но там можно выбрать только один пункт из раздела.

Фото:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. У woocommerce есть очень много насдстроек и плагинов. Ищите по ключевым словам виджеты woocommerce.
2. Даже если вы найдете то что вам надо или напишите сами вам придется встраивать это самому. Велика вероятность некорректной работы.